# Is there anyway to add a loading message to rich:dataTable?

Tags: jsf, richfaces, loading, message, richdatatable

Has anyone found a way of display a loading message while rich:dataTable loads?

I've found that if the load operations backing DataModel takes along time it results in the request taking along time. Is the an effective way of display a message to the user during this load?

I'm using Richfaces 3.3.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `a4j:status`. Refer to Exadel livedemo for more details: http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/status.jsf?c=status&tab=usage

If you need to show messages on data table interactions only, you can limit area for `a4j:status` by `a4j:region`:

```
<a4j:region>
    <a4j:status startText="Loading. Please wait..." >

    <rich:dataTable .../>
</a4j:region>
```

**UPDATE:**
For lazy loading of some content, the following approach can be used.
Create a facelet (or component):

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
            xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
            xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
            xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
            xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
<h:panelGroup id="lazyP#{id}" layout="block">
    <ui:fragment rendered="#{lazy.isRendered(id)}">
        <ui:insert name="lazy"/>
    </ui:fragment>
    <ui:fragment rendered="#{not lazy.isRendered(id)}">

        <h:outputText value="Loading..."/>

        <a4j:region>
            <a4j:jsFunction name="loadData#{id}" reRender="lazyP#{id}"
                            action="#{lazy.release(id)}"
                            limitToList="true"
                            ajaxSingle="true" eventsQueue="lazyQueue"/>
        </a4j:region>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                loadData#{id}();
            });
        </script>
    </ui:fragment>
</h:panelGroup>
```

`lazy` is reference of bean (I use page scope) which stores map of what was rendered and what was not (`release` method marks item as rendered).

Then you can use that like the following:

```
<ui:decorate template="lazyLoad.xhtml">
     <ui:param name="id" value="someId"/>
     <ui:define name="lazy">
           <rich:dataTable ... />
     </ui:define>
</ui:decorate>
```

Comment: This is useful for internal changes inside the table, datascroller, and basically anything on the page you can put in the a4j:region but for request coming from modals or other pages that update the table you need to do a separate status.

Comment: @James McMahon Can you describe a use case in the question? As I understand you need loading message even for GET requests (first page layout is displayed with Loading.. message, then table content (separate 'lazy' AJAX request to server?)).

Comment: @James McMahon That first method obviously is not about lazy loading. I have updated my answer with lazy loading solution. That solution uses some JBoss Seam features (page scope and method invocation with parameters in EL), I believe you will manage to do the same using just JSF 1.2 (e.g. functions for EL, and session scope or request scope+hidden fields instead of page scope).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I will have to try this out.